# Cant start session at login screen

Tags: 16.04, session

I followed an online guide which asked me to use the commands

Sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

This fails and it says that it depends on ubuntu-session
And there are broken packages

I proceed to do the following commands

Sudo apt-get clean

Sudo apt-get auto-clean

Sudo apt-get update --fix-missing

Sudo apt-get -f install

Sudo dpkg --configure -a

But the packages are still broken and I am unable to install ubuntu-session

I tried installing ubuntu-session

Sudo apt-get install ubuntu-session

But I get the broken packages message again with the following as an error:
Depends on gnome-session-common (= 3.18.1.2-1ubuntu1) but 3.18.1.2-1ubuntu1.16.0.4 is to be installed.
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I'm on my mobile phone so I can't format this properly.

Also reformatting is not possible as I wish to keep my files.

some screen shots when trying to install Ubuntu 
desktop/session:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nl0zp.jpg

Edit:
I have tried: `sudo apt-get upgrade -f` before everything typed above but I get the same results.

Also this is the link I was following to fix the "session failed to start" problem: https://itsfoss.com/failed-to-start-session-ubuntu-14-04/

I followed it but none of the solutions worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed with the following steps:

- Ctrl+Alt+F1 on login screen
- install aptitude `sudo apt-get install aptitude`
- `sudo aptitude install ubuntu-desktop`
- follow instructions aptitude gives

Aptitude will downgrade/remove broken packages before proceeding with the install.

Answer (score 0):

Open a **Terminal** and type the following:

```
sudo apt-get install x11-common
sudo apt-get install xserver-common
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
sudo apt-get install gnome
```

Then you have to install a Linux Desktop Environment such as:

- budgie-core
- unity
- ubuntu-walyland
- ubuntu-desktop

For example:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-walyland
```

Just choose which desktop environment fits your needs or install them all and remove what you don't like afterwards.